# Preserve Linux Capabilities in Debian Package

Tags: linux, permissions, deb

I'm building a package containing a web service that needs to listen on port 443. The service itself is written in Go, so I can't use authbind to manage the port permissions. Instead, I've opted to use setcap:

```
me@buildbox $ setcap CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE=+eip opt/myservice/myservice
me@buildbox $ getcap opt/myservice/myservice
opt/myservice/myservice = cap_net_bind_service+eip
```

However, this capability is not preserved when I install the package on my servers.

```
me@myserver $ apt-get install myservice
...
# installs normally
...
me@myserver $ getcap /opt/myservice/myservice
me@myserver $ # ^ No output == no capabilities
```

I really don't want this service to be run as root ever, but I'm having trouble coming up with a solution that is preserved when the package is installed. Can I somehow set capabilities in a debian package? Is there another method that achieves the desired end result (service can bind to port 443, but doesn't run as root).

Comment: Maybe setup a `postinst` script that sets the capabilities?

Comment: @Zoredache wow. I never knew that was a thing (I'm rather new to debian packaging). Thanks for pointing me in that direction, I'm guessing that will work.

Comment: BTW, looks like it isn't possible. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156421/can-capabilities-be-specified-in-debian-packages and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/debhelper/+bug/1371695

Comment: @Zoredache it actually works! My postinst contains the line `setcap CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE=+eip /opt/myservice/myservice`. After installation, the service has the correct capabilities. If you post as an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User Zoredache answered this in the comments. I'm posting this answer to make sure that people finding this question are aware that the problem was resolved.

In the debian package, I added a `postinst` file to `DEBIAN/`, which dpkg executes after copying files to the filesystem. The `postinst` contains the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
setcap CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE=+eip /opt/myservice/myservice
```

This worked for me. I don't remember now, but I believe the package did need to be installed by a user with sudo access on the destination machine.